# MySQL ORDER BY not most common

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Hello i have this table which contains users and the amount of points they have and i want to display the table starting from the users with the highest points but when i try the code below what it does is it shows the most common amount of points.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points ASC
```

But instead of

```
User | Points
Bob    20
Jon    16
Abu    16
Eli    15
```

It does

```
User | Points
Jon    16
Abu    16
Bob    20
Eli    15
```

See shouldn't 20 be on top? it does it by most common points any help I am new to PHP

EDIT: Thanks to Hanky 웃 Panky i realized what i needed to do

```
ORDER BY CAST(points AS unsigned) DESC
```

Is the correct way.

Comment: This cant be possible. can you give table data from where your values are comes?

Comment: ... or the table definition itself?

Comment: It is very easily possible Kaushal Khamar, if the Points field is not of a numeric data type and the sorting order becomes string based.

Comment: check the data type of points.. it should be int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Points` field must be a String to be interpreted that way. Cast it as a number( if you cant change data type to become a number permanently) and you are good.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY CAST(points AS unsigned) ASC
```

And for a Descending order, use `DESC` instead of `ASC`

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/096fd/2)**

Comment: Or better yet, change the column as unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

use

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC
```

for descending order

Answer (score 0):

Please, change of type points string to integer or numeric type.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE users MODIFY points INTEGER;
```